# Prove $\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_E f^{1/n}(x)dm=m(E)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $f:E \to \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable and non-negative function, with $0<f(x)<1$. I have to prove that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_E f^{1/n}(x)dm=m(E)$.

---

I've got various questions:

1. f is measurable and non-negative, but we don't know if it is non-decreasing, so we can't use the monotone convergence theorem, right? And is Fatou's lemma useful?
2. So what we have to use to enter the limit inside the integral is the dominated convergence theorem? But to use this, first I would have to see if its hypotheses are satisfied, right?
3. So now, $\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_E f^{1/n}(x)dm=\int_E \lim_{n\to \infty} f^{1/n}(x)dm=\int_E f^{0}(x)dm=\int_E dm=m(E)$

Could anyone answer those 3 questions, please? Is it ok what I have done?

Answer (score 2):

If $m(E) <\infty$ then DCT applies since $0< f^{1/n} \leq 1$. Suppose $m(E)=\infty$. Let $F_N=E\cap [-N,N]$. Then $\int_E f^{1/n}dm \geq \int_F f^{1/n}dm \to m(F)$. Can can finish the proof by letting $N \to \infty$?
MCT is also applicable since $ f^{1/n}$ is positive and increases to $1$.

Details for the first proof: $\lim \inf_{n \to \infty} \int_E f^{1/n}dm \geq \lim \inf_{n \to \infty} \int_{F_N} f^{1/n}dm =m(F_N)$. This is true for each $N$ and $F_N$ increase to $E$ as $N$ increases to $\infty$. Hence, $m(F_n) \to m(E)=\infty$ proving that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_E f^{1/n}dm=\infty$.

Comment: So the case $m(E)< \infty$ is ok as I have done the the point 3. , right? And the case $m(E)= \infty$ I don't understand what you want to say

Comment: @User160 If you cannot complete the argument using DCT, use MCT.  MCT gives  the answer immediately.  If $0<t<1$ then $t^{1/n}$ increases to $1$.

Comment: @User160 I have also added details for the first proof.

Comment: Other question: when $m(E)<\infty$,  $f^{1/n}$ is continuous because $f$ is continuous, right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. @User160

Answer (score 0):

Measurability issues are not complicated since $f$ is measurable. **You can use** the monotone convergence theorem, for  $0<f<1$, and so the sequence $h_n:=f^{1/n}$ is monotone increasing. Now $\lim_nf^{1/n}=1$; hence, an application of the monotone convergence theorem gives
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_Ef^{1/n}\,dm=\int_E\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f^{1/n}\,dm=\int_E\,dm=m(E)$$